# R Studio Server / Shiny Server Admin

Tags: shiny-server

I have 'inherited' from our previous resident data scientist, a RStudio Server setup on a remote virtual machine that we can use to host Shiny Apps.
I have basic experience on Unix i.e. Can mount files etc to the server from our Windows environment. 
The issue I am having is, now our DS has left, any apps placed on the location will not run due his login no longer existing. The message to that effect is displayed on the browser when trying to run any app from the created directory.
Does this mean the instance of RStudio Server / Shiny Server run must run from or as a specified admin? If so, how would one go about changing this to be able to use apps again?
I have trawled the admin guide but am both confused and at a loss as to what is required.
Any help would be appreciated.

Regards

Comment: Update: Cracked it. This was very helpful http://deanattali.com/2015/05/09/setup-rstudio-shiny-server-digital-ocean/#shiny-user-perms. Firstly ensured I had admin control on the Linux server, created a new group, then using vim (took a small bit of googling) edited the conf file to run-as new group. Quite easy really once I got round to it. In hindsight, the admin guide is quite good 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See comment. Fixed this with a bit of googling and actually properly reading the awesome admin guide. Get to know vim if not already familiar and you are there.
Sudo, Sudo and more Sudo